# Android Kotlin, managing a huge dictionary: Android Studio or Room Database?

Tags: kotlin, android-room, language-translation

I would like to know if an application would be more fluid by managing the translations of tens of thousands of elements in ten languages with Android Studio or with Room database? Or should I consider an alternative solution?

For the moment, I have not yet tested the different options. I'm completing xml files with my data using Android Studio's translation system and I've listed several tutorials on Room Database.

Comment: are you referring to app's strings translations? is your app a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to app's strings translations (string in values-en, values-es, etc.). No, it's not a dictionary app. But, there will be a lot of fact sheets.

Comment: You may wish to consider looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69056684/how-to-make-database-for-vocabulary-list-app-with-multiple-languages-like-google/69060539#69060539

Comment: Thanks for this link, it's well explained on how to manage translation with Room Databse. As I'm afraid to reach the limits of app's strings translations with Android Studio, I will surely opt for this method. But, if anyone has ever tested both options, I would like to know the performance results.