# Kotlin - Compose - Database with programmatically updatable number of columns

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I am trying to build my first app ever. I've chosen something fairly simple, card with words translated in different languages.

The main screen looks something like this (please do not pay attention to the horrible interface, I will take care of that in the end)

[image]

On this interface each word you see corresponds to the same meaning in a different language:

- "okhlh" is french for cow for example
- "kjsdsd" is german for cow for example
- etc...

When you click on the + button, you go to a new screen where you can add a word to the table where you came from.

[image]

This screen is related to two pieces of code, ItemEntryScreen and ItemEntryViewModel. This implementation is inspired from the [inventory](https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-inventory-app/tree/main) training app in the android jetpack compose tutorials.

ItemEntryScreen

```
object ItemEntryDestination : NavigationDestination {
    override val route = "item_entry"
    override val titleRes = R.string.item_entry_title
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ItemEntryScreen(
    navigateBack: () -> Unit,
    onNavigateUp: () -> Unit,
    canNavigateBack: Boolean = true,
    viewModel: ItemEntryViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory)
) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            LFCTopAppBar(
                title = stringResource(ItemEntryDestination.titleRes),
                canNavigateBack = canNavigateBack,
                navigateUp = onNavigateUp
            )
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        ItemEntryBody(
            itemUiState = viewModel.itemUiState,
            onItemValueChange = viewModel::updateUiState,
            onSaveClick = {
                // Note: If the user rotates the screen very fast, the operation may get cancelled
                // and the item may not be saved in the Database. This is because when config
                // change occurs, the Activity will be recreated and the rememberCoroutineScope will
                // be cancelled - since the scope is bound to composition.
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    viewModel.saveItem()
                    navigateBack()
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(innerPadding)
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .fillMaxWidth()
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ItemEntryBody(
    itemUiState: ItemUiState,
    onItemValueChange: (ItemDetails) -> Unit,
    onSaveClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.padding(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_medium)),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_large))
    ) {
        ItemInputForm(
            itemDetails = itemUiState.itemDetails,
            onValueChange = onItemValueChange,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
        Button(
            onClick = onSaveClick,
            enabled = itemUiState.isEntryValid,
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(text = stringResource(R.string.save_action))
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ItemInputForm(
    itemDetails: ItemDetails,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onValueChange: (ItemDetails) -> Unit = {},
    enabled: Boolean = true
) {

    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_medium))
    ) {
        if(itemDetails.translationList.isEmpty()){
            TranslationOutlinedTextField(0,itemDetails,"", R.string.frenchTranslation, onValueChange,  enabled)
            TranslationOutlinedTextField(1,itemDetails,"",R.string.englishTranslation, onValueChange, enabled)
            TranslationOutlinedTextField(2,itemDetails,"", R.string.espanolTranslation, onValueChange, enabled)
            TranslationOutlinedTextField(3,itemDetails,"", R.string.arabicTranslation,  onValueChange, enabled)
            TranslationOutlinedTextField(4,itemDetails,"", R.string.japaneseTranslation, onValueChange, enabled)

        }
        else {
            TranslationOutlinedTextField(
                0,
                itemDetails,
                itemDetails.translationList[0],
                R.string.frenchTranslation,
                onValueChange ,
                enabled
            )
            TranslationOutlinedTextField(
                1,
                itemDetails,
                itemDetails.translationList[1],
                R.string.englishTranslation,
                onValueChange ,
                enabled
            )
            TranslationOutlinedTextField(
                2,
                itemDetails,
                itemDetails.translationList[2],
                R.string.arabicTranslation,
                onValueChange,
                enabled
            )
            TranslationOutlinedTextField(
                3,
                itemDetails,
                itemDetails.translationList[3],
                R.string.japaneseTranslation,
                onValueChange,
                enabled
            )
            TranslationOutlinedTextField(
                4,
                itemDetails ,
                itemDetails.translationList[4],
                R.string.espanolTranslation,
                onValueChange,
                enabled
            )
        }

    }
}
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TranslationOutlinedTextField(index: Int, itemDetails: ItemDetails, translation: String?, @StringRes translationLabel: Int, onValueChange: (ItemDetails) -> Unit = {}, enabled: Boolean){
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = translation?:"",
        onValueChange = {when(index){
            0-> onValueChange(itemDetails.copy(frenchTranslation = it))
            1-> {onValueChange(itemDetails.copy(englishTranslation = it))}
            2-> {onValueChange(itemDetails.copy(arabicTranslation = it))}
            3-> {onValueChange(itemDetails.copy(japaneseTranslation = it))}
            4-> {onValueChange(itemDetails.copy(espanolTranslation = it))}
        }},
        label = { Text(stringResource(translationLabel)) },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        enabled = enabled,
        singleLine = true
    )
}
```

itemEntryViewModel

```
/**
 * ViewModel to validate and insert items in the Room database.
 */
class ItemEntryViewModel(
    private val itemsRepository: ItemsRepository
    ) : ViewModel() {
    /**
     * Holds current item ui state
     */
    var itemUiState by mutableStateOf(ItemUiState())
        private set

    /**
     * Updates the [itemUiState] with the value provided in the argument. This method also triggers
     * a validation for input values.
     */

    fun updateUiState(itemDetails: ItemDetails) {
        itemUiState =
            ItemUiState(
                itemDetails = itemDetails ,
                isEntryValid = validateInput(itemDetails))
    }



    /**
     * Inserts an [Item] in the Room database
     */
    suspend fun saveItem() {
        if (validateInput()) {
            itemUiState.showSuccessfulSubmissionSnackBar = true
            itemsRepository.insertItem(itemUiState.itemDetails.toItem())
        }
        else{
            itemUiState.showUnsuccessfulSubmissionSnackBar = true

        }
    }
    fun List<String?>.isListEmptyOrNull(): Boolean {
        val predicate: (String?) -> Boolean = { it?.length == 0 }
        val result=this.all(predicate)
        return (result)
    }
    private fun validateInput(uiState: ItemDetails = itemUiState.itemDetails): Boolean {
        return with(uiState) {
            !(translationList.isListEmptyOrNull())
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Represents Ui State for an Item.
 */


data class ItemUiState(
    val itemDetails: ItemDetails = ItemDetails(),
    val isEntryValid: Boolean = false,
    var showSuccessfulSubmissionSnackBar: Boolean =false,
    var showUnsuccessfulSubmissionSnackBar:  Boolean =false,
)

data class ItemDetails(
    val frenchTranslation: String="",
    val englishTranslation: String="",
    val arabicTranslation: String="" ,
    val japaneseTranslation: String="",
    val espanolTranslation: String=""
){
    val translationList: List<String?> = listOf(frenchTranslation,englishTranslation,arabicTranslation,japaneseTranslation,espanolTranslation)
}

/**
 * Extension function to convert [ItemUiState] to [Item].
 */
fun ItemDetails.toItem(): Item = Item(
    frenchTranslation  = translationList[0],
    englishTranslation = translationList[1],
    arabicTranslation = translationList[2],
    japaneseTranslation = translationList[3],
    espanolTranslation = translationList[4]
)
```

**The problem I am facing right now is that I am "hardcoding" every language, you will have noticed I am sure all the frenchTranslation, englishTranslation ... variables, and therefore if in the future I want to add a new language, it will take a long time!**

**Question:** How can I make this more programmatic so that if if in the future I add a language to the table (see image below), I won't have to go through the whole code and add `newLanguageTranslation` everywhere? I'd be more than satisfied with just a general strategy to follow/ concepts to apply, I do not need a precise implementation.

The database only table right now:
[image]

Some other pieces of code that maybe relevant.

Item Class

```
/**
 * Entity data class represents a single row in the database.
 */
@Entity(tableName = "items")
data class Item(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,
    val frenchTranslation: String? ="ha",
    val englishTranslation: String? ="ha",
    val arabicTranslation: String? ="ha",
    val japaneseTranslation: String? ="ha",
    val espanolTranslation: String? ="hi"
)
```

ItemDao

```
/**
 * Database access object to access the Inventory database
 */
@Dao
interface ItemDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from items ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun getAllItems(): Flow<List<Item>>

    @Query("SELECT * from items WHERE id = :id")
    fun getItem(id: Int): Flow<Item>

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(frenchTranslation) FROM items")
    fun getAllItemsCount(): Flow<Int>

    // Specify the conflict strategy as IGNORE, when the user tries to add 
    // existing Item into the database Room ignores the conflict.
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(item: Item)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(item: Item)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(item: Item)
}
```

LFCDatabase

```
/**
 * Database class with a singleton Instance object.
 */
@Database(entities = [Item::class], version = 2, exportSchema = false)
abstract class LFCDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun itemDao(): ItemDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var Instance: LFCDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): LFCDatabase {
            // if the Instance is not null, return it, otherwise create a new database instance.
            return Instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                Room.databaseBuilder(context, LFCDatabase::class.java, "flashCardDatabase")
                    /**
                     * Setting this option in your app's database builder means that Room
                     * permanently deletes all data from the tables in your database when it
                     * attempts to perform a migration with no defined migration path.
                     */
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .createFromAsset("flashCardDatabase.db")
                    .build()
                    .also { Instance = it }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

InterfaceRepository

```
/**
 * Repository that provides insert, update, delete, and retrieve of [Item] from a given data source.
 */
interface ItemsRepository {

    /**
     * Retrieve number of items from the the given data source.
     */
    fun getAllItemsCount(): Flow<Int>

    /**
     * Retrieve all the items from the the given data source.
     */
    fun getAllItemsStream(): Flow<List<Item>>

    /**
     * Retrieve an item from the given data source that matches with the [id].
     */
    fun getItemStream(id: Int): Flow<Item?>

    /**
     * Insert item in the data source
     */
    suspend fun insertItem(item: Item)

    /**
     * Delete item from the data source
     */
    suspend fun deleteItem(item: Item)

    /**
     * Update item in the data source
     */
    suspend fun updateItem(item: Item)
}
```

OfflineItemsRepository

```
class OfflineItemsRepository(private val itemDao: ItemDao) : ItemsRepository {

    override fun getAllItemsCount(): Flow<Int> = itemDao.getAllItemsCount()

    override fun getAllItemsStream(): Flow<List<Item>> = itemDao.getAllItems()

    override fun getItemStream(id: Int): Flow<Item?> = itemDao.getItem(id)

    override suspend fun insertItem(item: Item) = itemDao.insert(item)

    override suspend fun deleteItem(item: Item) = itemDao.delete(item)

    override suspend fun updateItem(item: Item) = itemDao.update(item)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried that taking the translations as a list of maps ? For example in your Entity data class you will have ```val translations: List<Map<String, String>>``` and then for every language you can update that list. Maybe ? Or better, you will have another data class ```Translation```which obviously takes translated word and language about it ?

Comment: I mean, I don't think you should create a new column for every list but instead storing all translations as list of maps in one column ? I hope i could explain properly

Comment: I would suggest having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69056684/how-to-make-database-for-vocabulary-list-app-with-multiple-languages-like-google/69060539#69060539